# gnuplot plotting time vs two data-set

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I have to plot three columns in a file using `gnuplot`. Here is sample input file and data of inputv1.dat file:

```
1498041447 2.0 0.0
1498041449 2.0 0.0
1498041451 2.0 0.0
1498041452 2.0 0.0
1498041453 2.0 0.0
1498041455 2.0 0.0
1498041456 2.0 0.0
1498041457 2.0 0.0
1498041458 2.0 0.0
1498041459 0.0 0.0
1498041460 0.0 0.0
1498041461 2.0 0.0
1498041461 0.0 0.0
1498041462 0.0 0.0
1498041463 2.0 0.0
```

Here is the code:

```
inputFile=inputv1.dat
/usr/bin/gnuplot << GPLOT
set terminal x11  enhanced title "CPU USAGE,MEMORY USAGE vs TIME" persist raise
set logscale xy
set xlabel "Time(10-sec interval)"
set ylabel "Run/Wait time"
plot  "$inputFile" smooth csplines using 3:1 ;
GPLOT
```

## Question:

I need to have 1st column(time in epoch) of inputv1.dat in x axis, whereas 2nd and 3rd column on y-axis.

Comment: `plot "$inputFile" smooth csplines u 1:2, "" smooth cspline u 1:3`, see [Basic plotting of data files](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/gnuplot/3591/basic-plotting-of-data-files#t=201706211121558004625)

Comment: @Christoph , helpful, thanks. I would appreciate one more help, here I am using epoch time hence I am getting a straight line. Can I scale down the time to get some meaningful plot ?

Comment: If I understand your question in the comment, I guess you want to shift the x-axis at origin. You could do something like `plot "$inputFile" smooth cspline u ($1-1498041447):2`